# How to query the scheduled jobs from Quartz scheduler?

Tags: java, quartz-scheduler

I have a `Scheduler` object in my application and I add `Job`s to it using the `scheduleJob` method.

In my code I schedule `Job`s with an instant `Trigger`:

```
TriggerBuilder.newTrigger().startNow().build();
```

My question is how to tell which `Job`s are scheduled into my `Scheduler`? There is only a `getCurrentlyExecutingJobs` method which seems unreliable so far.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The below code list all Quartz job associated to a scheduler (Quartz 2.x.x)

```
for (String groupName : scheduler.getJobGroupNames()) {

 for (JobKey jobKey : scheduler.getJobKeys(GroupMatcher.jobGroupEquals(groupName))) {

  String jobName = jobKey.getName();
  String jobGroup = jobKey.getGroup();

  //get job's trigger
  List<Trigger> triggers = (List<Trigger>) scheduler.getTriggersOfJob(jobKey);
  Date nextFireTime = triggers.get(0).getNextFireTime(); 

    System.out.println("[jobName] : " + jobName + " [groupName] : "
        + jobGroup + " - " + nextFireTime);

  }

}
```

Comment: By the time of your answer I've already figured out the solution but it is the same as yours, so I'll accept it.

Comment: copied from here https://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-list-all-jobs-in-the-quartz-scheduler/

Answer (score 0):

Another way to list all `JobKey` without using `for`

```java
List<JobKey> jobKeyList = (List<JobKey>) scheduler.getJobKeys(GroupMatcher.anyGroup());
```