# How the data is saved in the Quartz Database

Tags: java, spring, quartz-scheduler, quartz

I am new to Spring Quartz and I wanted to know :-

- How the data is saved in the database?
- How to retrieve the Values from the database?
- Can we create our own databases?
- How to delete the Job and triggers?

If possible please attach the document to work on Spring Quartz.

Comment: [quartz-spring](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/scheduling.html), [quartz job stores](http://www.quartz-scheduler.org/documentation/quartz-2.x/tutorials/tutorial-lesson-09.html), [quartz tutorials](http://www.quartz-scheduler.org/documentation/quartz-2.x/quick-start.html)

Comment: @yishaiz Can you please provide some information on how to retrieve data from the datastore. My data is getting saved in database successfully when i schedule a job, but how to fetch all the jobs from database, that are scheduled?

Comment: You should get your data through the Quartz APIs, e.g. for getting all scheduled jobs follow these examples: https://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-list-all-jobs-in-the-quartz-scheduler/, https://stackoverflow.com/a/22556598/3883957